# margins with option predict Stata 17

Tags: stata

I used to run this code in Stata 15:

```
qui foreach weight in no yes {
    foreach sample in pool female male{
        foreach out in delta var dnprob {
            foreach wave in 78 8ca {
            
                noi eoprobit `out'`wave' $exp ${`weight'} ${`sample'}, 
                    endogenous(home_both = i.iv2 $exp, probit) select(in_sample = i.iv1 i.iv2 $exp) vce(cluster cl_1) iterate(50)
                est store a
                cap noi margins if in_sample==1, dydx(home_both) post
                cap noi outreg2 using ${dir}\eoprobit.xls, excel append dec(3) ctitle(`out'`wave'_`weight') 

                est restore a
                est replay
                cap noi margins, dydx(iv1 iv2) predict(equation(in_sample)) at(iv2=0) post
                cap noi outreg2 using ${dir}\eoprobit.xls, excel append dec(3) ctitle(in_`out'`wave'_`weight') 
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

However, in Stata 17 it does not work anymore. In particular,  it does not allow the option predict(equation()) after margins. It does not understand that should pick the equation "in sample".
Any suggestion? Thanks for your invaluable help!